# Java Opening and Reading Files From a Directory

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have some code that opens up a directory, some subdirectories and then creates File objects for each txt file. I then have a Scanner to scan through each file. When I use scan.nextLine() though, it returns the name of the file to me, rather than opening the file and giving me those Strings. Here is the code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DirTest
{

public void start()
{
String [] fileListing = null;

    //directory code from project

    File topDir = new File("TopDirectory");
    if (topDir.isDirectory());
    {
        String [] dirList = topDir.list();
        for(String name : dirList)
        {
            File midDir = new File("TopDirectory", name);
            if(midDir.isDirectory())
            {
                fileListing = midDir.list();
                for(String name2: fileListing)
                {
                    File files = new File(name, name2); 
                    System.out.println("Directory: " + midDir);
                    System.out.println("File: " + files);

                    // Scanner section, scans through fileListing[] files//
                    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                    {
                        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileListing[i]);
                        String var1 = scan.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(var1);
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Should I be opening each file in some way before I scan? 
Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileListing[i]);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr);

    // Scan here

    fr.close();
```